# Google Custom Search / HtmlAgilityPack - Movie Showtimes in Windows store 8.1 app

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get showtimes for local cinemas using the postcode. I've done this before in a windows forms application by scraping the HTML with the htmlagilitypack.

I'm now developing an app for the kids and myself, I know that scraping the showtimes is frowned upon by Google and they can block your IP (this has actually happened to me once during testing).

Scraping the page is no longer viable because I don't have a good means of extracting the data with a deliminator

I have moved on to a windows store app and Googles custom search api. The issue i have with this is shown below,

1. Google.com  parm= BT48 // gives results but not on cinema listings
2. Google.com/Movies?near= // parm bt48 return null items
3. Google.com // parm Cinema Listings BT48 // Returns please enter valid location for showtime

   ```
   const string apiKey = "removed";
   const string searchEngineId = "removed";
   const string search = "cinema listing near bt48";


   Google.Apis.Customsearch.v1.CustomsearchService svc =  new Google.Apis.Customsearch.v1.CustomsearchService(new     Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer() { ApiKey = apiKey});


      Google.Apis.Customsearch.v1.CseResource.ListRequest listRequest =   svc.Cse.List(search);
      listRequest.Cx = searchEngineId;

        Google.Apis.Customsearch.v1.Data.Search gSearch = listRequest.Execute();
        //Google.Apis.Customsearch.v1.Data.Result

       foreach(Google.Apis.Customsearch.v1.Data.Result result in gSearch.Items)
       {
           var p = 0;            
       }
   ```

Does anyone know how I can pass a parameter to get the results or if I can even go about this in the correct way?

** SOLVED **
So after reading the google documentation i can see that i cannot get the page information without paying $100 a year for the functionality.

Since im a poor software developer i found a way to scrape the page.

If your reading this post its likely you too face the same issue im having so im sharing my solution. :)

private async void GetShowtimes()
        {

```
        // Load string 
        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlDocument htmldocument = await web.LoadFromWebAsync("http://google.com/movies?near=bt48");

        // Get theater collection
        var theaterCollection = htmldocument.DocumentNode.DescendantNodes().Where(x => x.GetAttributeValue("class","") == "theater").ToList();

        // Loop each theater and extact theater details and showing movie details
        foreach (HtmlNode  theater in theaterCollection )
        {
            string theaterName = theater.ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes[0].InnerText;
            string theaterAddress = theater.ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes[1].InnerText;

            HtmlDocument htmldocument2 = new HtmlDocument();
            htmldocument2.LoadHtml(theater.InnerHtml);

            var movieNodes = htmldocument2.DocumentNode.DescendantNodes().Where(x => x.GetAttributeValue("class", "") == "movie").ToList();

            foreach (HtmlNode movie in movieNodes)
            {
                string name = movie.ChildNodes[0].InnerText ;
                string info = movie.ChildNodes[1].InnerText;
                string times = movie.ChildNodes[2].InnerText.Replace("&nbsp","");
                times = times.Replace("<!--  -->", "");

                // Do something with your movies here
            }


        }

    }
```

Comment: So after reading the google documentation i can see that i cannot get the page information without paying $100 a year for the functionality.